# how can I simplify a regular expression generated from a DFA

Tags: java, regex, finite-automata

I try to implement the Brzozowski algebraic method using Java, to generate the regular expression of the langage accepted by a given DFA, The expression generated is correct but not simplified.

For example :
`E|(E)e(e)|(A|(E)e(A))(A|e|(B)e(A))*(B|(B)e(e))|(B|(E)e(B)|(A|(E)e(A))(A|e|(B)e(A))*(E|(B)e(B)))(B|e|(E)e(B)|(A|(E)e(A))(A|e|(B)e(A))*(E|(B)e(B)))*(E|(E)e(e)|(A|(E)e(A))(A|e|(B)e(A))*(B|(B)e(e)))`
(e = epsilon, E = the empty set)

instead of : `(A|B)*AB`

The "Transitive closure method" returns nearly the same result.

One of the solutions consists of minimizing the automaton, but i think it's too heavy to generate a simplified regular expression.

also, using Java regular expressions methods to simplify a regular expression is not pretty at all :) .

So, it would be nice to try helping me to find a solution.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. This answer in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) may be of interest, though: [DFA versus NFA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978438/dfa-vs-nfa-engines-what-is-the-difference-in-their-capabilities-and-limitations), as listed in the "General" section.

Comment: The dk.brics.automaton library contains a few different minimization algorithms that you might study.  I don't think that library can convert an automaton back into a regular expression, but you seem to already know how to do that.

Comment: This looks like an Automata homework question. I would highly advise showing more insight into what you're trying to accomplish as well as any attempts you've tried. Showing you've taken a crack at the problem will provide motivation for giving you assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Take a look at this [Peter Norvig article](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313.ipynb?create=1). Oh! There is a [second part](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/norvig.com/ipython/xkcd1313-part2.ipynb?create=1). The solution is in python, but you can easily adapt it.