# Matching multi line HTML blocks , why so greedy?

Tags: php, html, regex, multiline, greedy

I have tried to get this working for most of the day.
At this point I can't even remember what I have tried and what I haven't tried, so now I'm asking for help!

I'm going to be using php's `preg_replace()` to delete  stanzas out of svg code.

But the problem I am facing can be shown with this much simpler example:

```
<div>
TRUE
</div>

<div>
FALSE
</div>

<div>
MAYBE
</div>
```

How do I match the middle div?
A simple version of my regular expression is

```
(?s)<div.*?FALSE.*?<\/div>
```

[That doesn't work](https://regex101.com/r/INCWGr/1), as it will match the first 2 divs, instead of only the middle one.

(is it still called greedy when it expands the match to the left?)

All the variations I tried got me nowhere.
I'm sure there is a simple answer, I just couldn't find it on my own.

Comment: And now, [it works](https://regex101.com/r/INCWGr/2).

Comment: Sorry, didn't even see your answer.
Yes that is spot on.
I don't post questions often, 3min from Q to A is better than I could have imagined.

Comment: Please remove this duplicate post. There are a lot of such questions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385942/why-is-this-simple-non-greedy-regex-being-greedy) is one although [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240408/regular-expressions-ensuring-b-doesnt-come-between-a-and-c/37240700#37240700) is quite generic.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, of course I found a solution shortly after I posted the question.

[This one works](https://regex101.com/r/EVR8wN/1)

Basically the original regex started with

```
<div.*?
```

And the correct answer was to replace that `.`  with

```
(?:.(?!<div))
```

Which is a non-capture group, using `.` with a negative look-ahead for `<div`
Since neither a look-ahead nor a look-behind can be part of a match .... This amounts to: match "Anything" except `<div`