# How to match closest text in group?

Tags: python, regex

I have string bellow

```
object1: {
   a: 'text a',
   b: 'text b',
},
object2: {
   a: 'text2 a',
   b: 'text2 b',
}
```

I have regex

```
r"(object1|object2):\s\{(?:.*?)(\w+):\s[\'\"]text2 b[\'\"]" with flags re.DOTALL
```

I expected is `('object2', 'b')`

But actual is `('object1', 'b')`

Comment: That's because non-greedy matching works forward, not backwards. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385942/why-is-this-simple-non-greedy-regex-being-greedy

Comment: I would recommend parsing this with a JSON parser instead of a Regex, by the way.

Comment: @joanis this string in a file javascript so I can't JSON parser

Comment: To solve your problem, you have to replace `.*?` by something that would not match `object?`, e.g., `...\s\{(?!.*object)(?:.*?)(\w+)...`, but this is just a hint, because it will fail on you if `object` occurs anywhere later in the string, so this won't fully solve your problem.

Comment: But your question is tagged python, so maybe https://www.google.com/search?q=json+parser+python

Comment: @joanis Thank you for your advice, I have fixed `(object1|object2):\s\{.(?:(?!}).)*?(\w+):\s[\'\"]text2 b[\'\"]`

Comment: If just blocking `}` is enough for you, I would go with @LouisCaron's solution, it will be more efficient, and it should match the same strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated non-greediness works forward, not on already matched groups.  One solution could be to introduce a failing search element in your forward matching group:

```
r"(object1|object2):\s\{(?:[^}]*?)(\w+):\s[\'\"]text2 b[\'\"]"
```

In this possible solution, the char '}' is excluded from the matching elements before matching the subelements of the structure, which makes sense.