# How to match regular expression even less greedy than not-greedy?

Tags: regex, pcre

This question focuses on *pcre*-regular expression as used by `grep -P`.

Imagine I have a string `abcRabcSxyxz` and search for a substring which starts with `abc` and ends with `x`, but with the restriction that no shorter substring of this match would also also match.

My first attempt was a non-greedy regexp,

```
grep -Po 'abc.*?x' <<<abcRabcSxyxz
```

but this returns *abcRabcSx*, while I would like to find just *abcSx*. It is obvious why even my non-greedy attempt still provides a match which is too long; I need the regexp engine to try harder. My second attempt was

```
grep -Po '(?>abc.*?)x' <<<abcRabcSxyxz
```

which did not provide a match at all (maybe I don't really understand the usage of `($?...)` explained [here](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC17)).

Any easy solution for my problem anyone?

**UPDATE** I see from the comments that my example does not precisely explain what i am searching for, so here a more general description:

I am searching for matches of the form `PXQ`, wher P, X and Q are arbitrary patterns, and X should **not** contain a match of P. Plus, I don't want to literally retype the pattern P inside X.

For instance

```
`[(][^(]*[)]`
```

would be a possible (but not satsifying) solution for the concrete case that I am searching for a parenthesized expression which does not contain another parenthesized (here, P is [(], X is an arbitrary string, and Q is [)]), but even this example shows that I have to **literally repeat** the information contained in P, when specifying the middle part ([^(]*), to make sure that my P is not contained there). I am looking for a way which makes this explicit repetition unnecessary.

Comment: Maybe with a negative lookahead: `abc(.(?!abc))*?x` (although not sure how this will perform).

Comment: This would work: `grep -Po 'abc.*\Kabc.*?x' <<<abcRabcSxyxz` in your case at least. Look for "Resetting the match start" in the docs. Whether or not that's good practice I don't know.

Comment: What if the string is something like `abc1xabc123x`? Or is that not possible?

Comment: @FelixKling : This would work for the concrete exampl I gave, but would not work for instance for the slightly modified `grep -Po 'abc.*\Kabc.*?x' <<<abcRabSxyxz` (which should return _abcRabSx_ as the shortest match), though I don't see why.

Comment: @FelixKling : Yes. I think I will update my question to make the matching criterion more clear.

Comment: The prefix would have to be made optional to match your new example: `(abc.*)?\Kabc.*?x` (still don't know whether that's the right way to go about it).

Comment: See https://ideone.com/WYKWqa

Comment: @FelixKling : Your new solution, and also the one linked to by Wiktor Stribizew, and by the moderators you decided that my question is a duplicate (and this was indeed the case before I updated it and provided more details), let me conclude that there seems to be indeed no good solution for my problem.

Comment: Recursive patterns might be what you are looking for but how to integrate "not P" into "X" might depend on what "X" is in the end. https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC25  . E.g. `([(])[^(?1)]+[)]` for your parenthesis example.

Comment: @FelixKling : I like the idea, but it means that the middle part must say something like: _Zero or more items which do **not** match the first group, what ever it is_. I don't see how to express this general _do no match_. I tried `'(abc)(?!?1)*?x'`, on the grounds that `(?!...)` says "do not match this", but get an error '_nothing to repeat_'. It seems that the `?1` does not pick up the `(abc)`.

Comment: You need `()` around the reference: `(?1)`. This seems to work: `(abc).(?!(?1))*?x`.

Comment: This questions seems to address your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385942/why-does-a-simple-non-greedy-regex-greedily-include-additional-characters-be . Instead of repeating the pattern you can use the recursive reference.

Comment: @FelixKling : The solution there is pretty much the same as I tried in my last comment (except the additonal use of a non-capturing group `(?:...)`), but anyway, adapting the example `HOHO(?:(?!HOHO).)*?_HO_` in that article to my case, would give `grep -Po '(abc)(?:(?!(?1).))*?x' <<<abcRabcSxyxz`, which does **not** match. Could it be due to a difference between the pcre engines in Javascript and in grep?

Comment: Mmh, it works when I put the `.` before negative lookahead... strange.

Comment: @user1934428: Your adaptation is wrong, the correct pattern will be: `grep -Po '(abc)(?:(?!(?1)).)*?x'`. Also, Javascript doesn't use the pcre regex engine and doesn't have the `(?n)` feature to refer to a subpattern. To do it in javascript, you have to rewrite the full subpattern: `/abc(?:(?!abc).)*?x/` (but nothing forbids to build your pattern dynamically using the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : Thanks for explaining. Indeed, this works! I was refering to Javascript only because the thread refered to by Wiktor Stribitzew discussed a Javascript solution. In case enough moderators vote to reopen my question, could you propose your solution as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte : As the question is open for answers, may I ask you to add your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. Much of this having been worked out in comments, thanks Casimir et Hippolyte, Felix Kling, and user1934428.

The solution uses PCRE and is as follows:

```
grep -Po '(abc)(?:(?!(?1)).)*?x' <<< abcRabcSxyxz
```

We know the result will start with "abc" and end in "x". So let us wall through how this result works.

- We group the expected output `(abc)` to start.
- A `(` followed by `?:` prevents the subpattern from capturing or counted.
- Next up is a negative look ahead assertions `(?!`.
- The subject of the look ahead is matched pattern 1 (in this case `abc`).
- The `.` matches any character, in this case matching the `S`.
- Ending the group with `)*?`, an un-greedy, matching few as zero characters.
- The final entry is the `x`, which the question designated as the ending character.